# login with different password column name in database

Tags: laravel

for some reason I had to deal with an old database table that contain users table. Password column is named as `password_hash`.

How can I login by using

```php
Auth::attempt([....])
```

When it comes to login. I already know that we can override email with

```php
public function username(){
   return 'username';
}
```

Is there any similar function to password?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a method to change the `password` column logic (i.e. use `password_hash` instead of `password`), but can you simply update the column name to `password`? Do you need to preserve this name for some kind of backwards compatibility?

Comment: The same table works in another different system built on Yii framework. So We do not need to update it.

Comment: Makes sense! Are both systems going to be using this database in tandem, or are you "sunsetting" the Yii one and moving to Laravel? If that is the case, you can probably safely rename the column to `password` and move along. If you need to support both, then I'm not sure; I'll see if I can find anything relevant in Laravel's documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me.

Since my User model is extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` and this class is use the `Authenticatable` trait, you can override the `getAuthPassword()` method,

```
public function getAuthPassword(){
    return $this->your_custom_password_column;
}
```